# Communication between WPF and microservices

Tags: wpf, asp.net-core, microservices

Is it possible to have communication between **WPF client app** written in .net framework and **microservices** written in .net core?

Comment: Yes. You will make Http calls to the ASP.NET Core microservice by using the HttpClient.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.

Microservices are services.

They would usually be http and could be REST. Web API would be the commonly used option with core.

The fact the service is written in .net core would make no difference because it's just HTTP.

You could make the call from wpf using httpclient.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/hh193681(v=vs.118)

Example code

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/advanced/calling-a-web-api-from-a-net-client